# Setting PDF boxes correctly in LaTeX

Tags: pdf, crop, cropmarks

This question is similar to [How to get correct PDF boxes (especially regarding bleeding and the TrimBox) in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370749/how-to-get-correct-pdf-boxes-especially-regarding-bleeding-and-the-trimbox-in/370935) which deals with ConTeXt.

I am using (Lua)LaTeX to produce a5-sized booklet for printing. The printing company wants to have extra bleed space (there are thumb marks and other material going up to the margin), so I used the crop package and b5 physical page size. However, even though the result is visually correct, the crop package only sets MediaBox in the PDF file (I deflated the PDF by using `qpdf -qdf --object-streams=disable in.pdf out.pdf`):

```
%% Page 1
%% Original object ID: 174 0
8 0 obj
<<
  /Annots 23 0 R
  /Contents 24 0 R
  /MediaBox [
    0
    0
    498.898
    708.661
  ]
  /Parent 11 0 R
  /Resources 26 0 R
  /Type /Page
>>
endobj
```

so MediaBox is set to b5 but there is no mention of A5 CropBox/TrimBox/BleedBox - so (I assume) the printer has to manually set the crop area based on crop marks.

Another − but related − issue is that [thumbs marks](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/thumbs) are misplaced when crop is used.

The question: how to do cropping correctly with (Lua)LaTeX, including setting respective PDF boxes?